# How do I get the parent UiSelector starting at its child?

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, appium-android, android-uiautomator

Note: Working with Java 11 and Appium.

I am trying to get a MobileElement for an appium test suite using Android UiAutomators. Specifically I need to scroll to one so I am condtructing the locator using `@AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector()...)"`. My problem is that the element I need has no unique identifiers but a child does.

Element tree looks something like this

```xml
<RecyclerView>
   <LinearLayout>
      <TextView text="name">
      <LinearLayout>
         <TextView text="type">
         <TextView text="unique id"> <---I can find this
      <Switch> <--- Element I need
   <LinearLayout>
      <TextView text="name">
      <LinearLayout>
         <TextView text="type">
         <TextView text="another unique id">
      <Switch>
```

I tried `new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains("unique text").fromParent(new UiSelector())` but that only gives me the other TextView under the LinearLayout. I have also tried `.childSelector()` and other paths but since the TextView is the only unique element I always end up at it with no way to move back up the tree. The Android developer documentaion on UiSelectors has not been helpful for me.

In short I want to go from (TextView text="unique id") get parent (LinearLayout) from there find (Switch) sibling. Once I have the specific (LinearLayout) I can get the (Switch) easily. Its getting the parent from the child that I can't seen to figure out. Any advice?

---

Context Not needed to Answer Question:

The RecyclerView has dozen of this LinearLayouts, so my ultimate goal is to have a java method that finds the switch based on the unique id and name combo. The name, type, and id are not unique in my actual code but the the name and id make a unique pair. This fact can be ignored for the above question, just wanted to provide context for the below. can be shared across elements but the id is always unique.

```java
private WebElement getSwitch(String name, String uniqueId){
   return driver.findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator(
      String.format("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true))"+
      ".scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"%s\")"+
      ".getParentofTextViewSomehow().fromParent(new UiSelector().text(\"%s\")"+
      ".fromParent(new UiSelector().className(\"Switch\"))))",uniqueId, name)));
}
```